# mobileのsafariでページを表示した段階でfocusをあてたい(入力可能な状態にしたい)

Tags: jquery, safari

mobileのsafariにて、画面を表示した段階でfocusをあてて入力可能な状態にしたいのですが 
focusが上手く動作しません。 
(focusがあたってはいるのかもしれませんが、キーボードが表示されない状態です)

iOSのsafariの場合、clickなどのイベントにbindしたらfocusが効くようになるとの記事等は見つけたのですが、click自体しないでfocusを当てておきたいため、上手くいっておりません。 
HTML

```
<form id="sample">
   <input type="text" id="text" />
   <input id="bind" type="button" value="バインドさせるボタン" />
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#sample', function() {
   var onClickHandler = function () {
      $('#text').focus();
   }
   $('#bind').on('click', onClickHandler);
   /*  #bindをクリックすると#textにfocusはあいますが、
   *  setTimeout('$("#bind").click()', 1000);
   *  のように操作してもキーボードが表示されない状態です
   */
});
```

どなたか方法をご存知のかたはいらっしゃいますでしょうか。 
よろしくお願いします。